# Отправка файлов на сервер с большой вложенностью объекта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, файлы, fetch, formdata

Мне нужно на сервер передать объект formdata с такой структурой. Могу ли передавать файлы в таком формате если вложенность файлов объект>объект>объект и объект>массив>объект
Поля с файлами user_info.company.certificate_file, user_docs[0].document, user_info.avatar и user_info.baner

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "username": "",
    "email": "",
    "user_info": {
      "id": 0,
      "first_name": "",
      "last_name": "",
      "father_name": "",
      "avatar": file,
      "on_vacation": true,
      "phone_number": "",
      "date_of_birth": "",
      "experiense": "",
      "cost_of_hour_work": "",
      "profile_description": "",
      "baner": file,
      "adress": "",
      "skill": "",
      "review_ratio": "",
      "company": {
        "id": 0,
        "employee_position": "",
        "company_name": "",
        "short_company_name": "",
        "ceo_name": "",
        "ceo_post": "",
        "adress_in_law": "",
        "adress_fact": "",
        "reg_number": "",
        "company_number": "",
        "kpp_number": "",
        "certificate": "",
        "certificate_file": file,
        "company_site": "",
        "company_phone": "",
        "company_email": "",
        "social_site": ""
      }
    },
    "user_docs": [
      {
        "document": file,
        "document_name": "",
        "personal_number": "",
        "document_number": "",
        "document_issued": "",
        "user": 0
      }
    ],
    "status": "",
    "legal_status": ""
  }
```

Comment: Ну а почему нет?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сгенерировать форму в таком стиле

Объекты

```
formData.append("user_info[company][id]", "QWerty");
```

Массивы

```
formData.append("user_docs[][document]", file);
formData.append("user_docs[][document_name]", "");
formData.append("user_docs[][personal_number]", "");
```